# aggregate data frame by equal buckets

Tags: r

I would like to aggregate an R data.frame by equal amounts of the cumulative sum of one of the variables in the data.frame. I googled quite a lot, but probably I don't know the correct terminology to find anything useful.

Suppose I have this data.frame:

```
> x <- data.frame(cbind(p=rnorm(100, 10, 0.1), v=round(runif(100, 1, 10))))
> head(x)
           p  v
1  10.002904  4
2  10.132200  2
3  10.026105  6
4  10.001146  2
5   9.990267  2
6  10.115907  6
7  10.199895  9
8   9.949996  8
9  10.165848  8
10  9.953283  6
11 10.072947 10
12 10.020379  2
13 10.084002  3
14  9.949108  8
15 10.065247  6
16  9.801699  3
17 10.014612  8
18  9.954638  5
19  9.958256  9
20 10.031041  7
```

I would like to reduce the x to a smaller data.frame where each line contains the weighted average of p, weighted by v, corresponding to an amount of n units of v. Something of this sort:

```
> n <- 100
> cum.v <- cumsum(x$v)
> f <- cum.v %/% n
> x.agg <- aggregate(cbind(v*p, v) ~ f, data=x, FUN=sum)
> x.agg$'v * p' <- x.agg$'v * p' / x.agg$v
> x.agg
  f     v * p   v
1 0 10.039369  98
2 1  9.952049  94
3 2 10.015058 104
4 3  9.938271 103
5 4  9.967244 100
6 5  9.995071  69
```

First question, I was wondering if there is a better (more efficient approach) to the code above. The second, more important, question is **how to correct the code above in order to obtain more precise bucketing**. Namely, each row in `x.agg` should contain exacly `100` units  of `v`, not just approximately as it is the case above. For example, the first row contains the aggregate of the first 17 rows of `x` which correspond to 98 units of `v`. The next row (18th) contains 5 units of `v` and is fully included in the next bucket. What I would like to achieve instead would be attribute 2 units of row 18th to the first bucket and the remaining 3 units to the following one.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another method that does this with out repeating each `p` `v` times. And the way I understand it is, the place where it crosses 100 (see below)

```
18  9.954638  5  98
19  9.958256  9 107
```

should be changed to:

```
18    9.954638  5  98
19.1  9.958256  2 100 # ---> 2 units will be considered with previous group
19.2  9.958256  7 107 # ----> remaining 7 units will be split for next group
```

**The code:**

```
n <- 100
# get cumulative sum, an id column (for retrace) and current group id
x <- transform(x, cv = cumsum(x$v), id = seq_len(nrow(x)), grp = cumsum(x$v) %/% n)

# Paste these two lines in R to install IRanges
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("IRanges")

require(IRanges)
ir1 <- successiveIRanges(x$v)
ir2 <- IRanges(seq(n, max(x$cv), by=n), width=1)
o <- findOverlaps(ir1, ir2)

# gets position where multiple of n(=100) occurs
# (where we'll have to do something about it)
pos <- queryHits(o)
# how much do the values differ from multiple of 100?
val <- start(ir2)[subjectHits(o)] - start(ir1)[queryHits(o)] + 1
# we need "pos" new rows of "pos" indices
x1 <- x[pos, ]
x1$v <- val # corresponding values
# reduce the group by 1, so that multiples of 100 will
# belong to the previous row
x1$grp <- x1$grp - 1
# subtract val in the original data x
x$v[pos] <- x$v[pos] - val
# bind and order them    
x <- rbind(x1,x)
x <- x[with(x, order(id)), ]
# remove unnecessary entries
x <- x[!(duplicated(x$id) & x$v == 0), ]
x$cv <- cumsum(x$v) # updated cumsum

x$id <- NULL
require(data.table)
x.dt <- data.table(x, key="grp")
x.dt[, list(res = sum(p*v)/sum(v), cv = tail(cv, 1)), by=grp]
```

Running on your data:

```
#    grp       res  cv
# 1:   0 10.037747 100
# 2:   1  9.994648 114
```

Running on @geektrader's data:

```
#    grp       res  cv
# 1:   0  9.999680 100
# 2:   1 10.040139 200
# 3:   2  9.976425 300
# 4:   3 10.026622 400
# 5:   4 10.068623 500
# 6:   5  9.982733 562
```

Here's a benchmark on a relatively big data:

```
set.seed(12345)
x <- data.frame(cbind(p=rnorm(1e5, 10, 0.1), v=round(runif(1e5, 1, 10))))

require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(out <- FN1(x), replications=10)

#            test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 1 out <- FN1(x)           10  13.817        1    12.586
```

It takes about **1.4 seconds** on 1e5 rows.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for precise bucketing, I am assuming value of p is same for 2 "split" v
i.e. in your example, value of p for 2 units of row 18th that go in first bucket is 9.954638

With above assumption, you can do following for not super large datasets..

```
> set.seed(12345)
> x <- data.frame(cbind(p=rnorm(100, 10, 0.1), v=round(runif(100, 1, 10))))
> z <- unlist(mapply(function(x,y) rep(x,y), x$p, x$v, SIMPLIFY=T))
```

this creates a vector with each value of p repeated v times for each row and result is combined into single vector using unlist.

After this aggregation is trivial using `aggregate` function

```
> aggregate(z, by=list((1:length(z)-0.5)%/%100), FUN=mean)
  Group.1         x
1       0  9.999680
2       1 10.040139
3       2  9.976425
4       3 10.026622
5       4 10.068623
6       5  9.982733
```

Comment: where can I find this `index` function?

Comment: @Arun oh my bad. I think it's function from xts which was already loaded.  It can be replaced with rownames and result will still be valid. Or even seq from 1 to nrow(z)